# Can I use RMI to test a cloud scheduling algorithm?

Tags: cloud, rmi, scheduling, simulator

I've a new -small- proposed cloud scheduling algorithm, and I need to simulated the cloud environment and test this Job scheduling algorithm.

my doctor suggested for me RMI but she is not sure how can I collect and analyze the results.

my question is:

- is RMI a good solution to do my work?
- Since OPNET is something I cannot afford, is there a good available simulator you recommend?

Hope to find a help..
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you have a professor, I am guessing you are working in an academic environment, in which case presumably an open-source tool would be useful- have you looked at [CloudSim](http://www.cloudbus.org/cloudsim/)? I don't know if it does exactly what you're looking for, but if it is open source at least you can tweak it if you need to.

As for RMI, it depends a little on what data you are planning to collect and how- I would perhaps think about simply logging during the simulation and then collating the logs somewhere central afterwards so they can be analysed by whatever tools you want. That would not give you real time feedback but would allow you to evaluate your data in a lot of different ways, which is likely to be more informative in the long term.

Comment: The data I want to collect are the data that evaluate my proposed algorithm -like the response time- can I do that in RMI? I'll check the cloudsim too, the name sounds interesting for my problem

Comment: Can you give me an example for the tools I can use to analyze the results?

Comment: @glenatron.. Hope to get an answer from you

Comment: It depends what they are, but I would be thinking about storing logs per instance as well as logging calls between them then importing them into a central database where you could run whatever analysis you want against the data using whatever reporting tools you have available. In depth data analysis is not my speciality, but that is how I would approach the problem. Start from what data you plan to draw conclusions on and work back to find what you should collect, that will probably also indicate how.